# button like articles in jquery php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following button

```
<a href='?area=ref&acao=like&news=$news->profile&id=$user ">like</a>";
```

This tells `action.php` that we liked the article, but when the button is clicked, it redirects to the `action.php` page and changes the content.

How do I just run the function in `action.php` without redirecting?

Comment: Your question wasn't entirely clear. I've edited it to be what I _think_ you wanted. Please check I haven't misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something called [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). To quote the linked article

> AJAX ... can send as well as receive information in a variety of formats, including JSON, XML, HTML, and even text files. AJAX’s most appealing characteristic, however, is its "asynchronous" nature, which means it can do all of this without having to refresh the page. This lets you update portions of a page based upon user events.

Once you've got the hang of it, look into using jQuery, specifically the [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) functionality. It will make your life easier by removing the browser-specific code and giving you a flexible framework to build on.